# Generating entity relationship diagram in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql, database, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, entity-relationship

Can you tell me how I can generate an ER diagram for my database1 (see below) created with VS 2015

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have outlined the steps on how to create the `Entity Relationship Diagram` with visual studio from your existing database in an answer below. Let me know if it solves your problem

Answer (score -4, accepted):

DB Objects in the editor will be related as in Diagram so Just relate objects in the Db and drag to editor.

Comment: I can't find what you say

Comment: No Body has a clue ? :(

Comment: OK.

You should do relations between tables on SQL . Then when you drag tables on the visual studio editor , editor will display relations visualy same as in diagrams on SQL editor.

Comment: thanks you @shukri gashi for your answer. I did the relations between tables on SQL, but I don't have such thing called "the visual studio editor "

Answer (score 24):

Ensure you installed either Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools or Microsoft Web Developer Tools in order to get the Entity Data Model Designer.

These are the steps to generate entity relationship diagram. It was tested in `VS2012`

1. Open `Visual Studio`
2. Create a project or open an existing project
   (must be Visual Basic, Visual C# project, or Console Application)
3. Right-click the project and choose `Add` -> `New Item…`
4. Under Visual C# Items select `“Data”`
5. Select the template `“ADO.NET Entity Data Model”`
6. Give it a name and click `“Add”`
7. Select `“Generate from database”` or `“Empty model”`
8. If `“Generate from database”` selected enter connection
   info, choose the database objects and done!

The model is stored as a `“.edmx”` file.

Comment: Simple, concise. This works perfectly for me. Not only do you get an ER diagram, but if you just create a new project you also have all the POCOs.

Comment: Still a valid solution for VS2022

Answer (score 1):

With Visual Studio you can [create a static diagram (class diagram)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hyxd8c85.aspx) but not entity relationship diagrams (for you DB).
You will have to use another tool for this. For SQL server [you can use SQL server Management Studio](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BNx1TYItQn4).

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 2016 doesn't have this feature anymore.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio v17.9 and it has the option to create database diagrams.

Comment: SSMS 18.x also has diagramming: `Object Explorer > YourDB > Database Diagrams > New Diagram`